# ngOnInit() not called in a component dart with angular2

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-routing

I have an app_component.dart that call this function

```
class OtherComponent {
  // ChromeCast receveiver event handler
  onLoad() { 
    this.router.navigate(["/Video", { 'pageData': pageData}]);
  }
}
```

To load another dart component called  video_component.dart.

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2/common.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';
import 'dart:js';
import 'dart:html';


@Component(selector: 'video-container', templateUrl: '../../views/video_component.html', directives: const [NgFor])
class VideoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  ContentService contentService;

  LoggerService log;

  String progress;

  RouteParams routeParams;

  var pageData;

  VideoComponent(@Inject(ContentService) this.contentService, @Inject(LoggerService) this.log, this.routeParams) {
    log.info('constructor called'); // <== constructor is called
  }

  @override
  ngOnInit() {
    log.info('ngOnInit:Load video page with content Id');
    //not called
  }
}
```

Why doesn't `ngOnInit()` not get called?

Comment: `(@Inject(ContentService) ` is redundant if the parameter has a type. This works also for parameters of kind `this.someField`. The last sentence seems incomplete.

Comment: yes. constructor has been called. with "new Future()" the compiler says 'Undefined class Future'

Comment: What is the `onLoad()` event, where does it come from?

Comment: it's a ChromeCast receveiver event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
NgZone zone;
ParentComponent(this.zone);

onLoad(event) {
  zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(...)
}
```

I assumed ParentComponent is the component that contains the event handler onLoad(event) ... and it's the constructor and used to inject NgZone like you did with ContentService and LoggerService in the code of your question. Change ParentComponent to the name of the class you use for this component.

The `onLoad()` from ChromeCast seems not to be patched from Angular and therefore doesn't run in Angulars zone. Now when the event handler is called from code outside Angulars zone some things don't work anymore (change detection for example).

With `zone.run(...)` we bring the context back to Angulars zone explicitely.